# Fetch sum of column

Tags: react-admin

I am using React-Admin to create little app for evidence of tools and who borrowed them.

I have table of tools with id, code, name, state atd.

using List to render it.

```
    <List {...props} filters={<ToolFilter />}>
        <Datagrid rowClick="edit">
            <TextField source="id" />
            <TextField source="code" label="Kód" />
            <TextField source="name" />
            <TextField source="state" />
            <NumberField source="free" />
            <DateField source="add_time" />
            <EditButton />
        </Datagrid>
    </List>
```

Than I have table B_tools, that holds data of borrowed tools.
it has id, userId, toolId, durationOfBorrow

What I want to do is to add column to the tools list, that SUMs durationOfBorrow from B_tool table for every tool  and render it to list of tools.

for example if I have B_tool table:

```
id   userId   toolId   durationOfBorrow
1    1        1        7
2    1        1        7
3    2        2        2
4    1        2        2
```

I need list of tools to look like this:

```
id   code     name     state   durationOfBorrow
1    123      Drill    1       14 (7+7)
2    456      Wrench   1       4 (2+2)
```

I tried use Querying The API With fetch from React-Admin documentation.
I have prepared route app.get('/api/tools/borrowcount:id', toolController.borrowCount); that shoud return sum of column:

```
borrowCount(req, res) {
        //console.log(req);  
        const filtry = JSON.parse(req.query.filter);
        console.log(filtry);



        const options = {
            attributes: [
                [sequelize.fn('sum', sequelize.col('time')), 'total_time'],
              ],
            raw: true,
            where: ({

            }),
            order: 
                []
            ,
        };


        if (typeof filtry.id !== "undefined") {
            options.where.id = filtry.id;
        }

        return B_tool
        .findAll(options)
            //console.log(user);
            //res.status(201).send(test); 
        .then(b_tool => {
            //console.log(user.rows);
            res.status(200).send(b_tool);
        })
        .catch(error => res.status(400).send(error));
    },
```

But dont know how to implement it to show it in the tools list.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

I created element BorrowCount that useQuery api/toolsborrow/:id and returns total_time.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useQuery, Loading, Error } from 'react-admin';

const BorrowCount = ({ record }) => {

    const { data, loading, error } = useQuery({ 
        type: 'getOne',
        resource: 'toolsborrow',
        payload: { id: record.id }
    });

    if (loading) return <Loading />;
    if (error) return <Error />;
    if (!data) return null;
    console.log(data);
    return (
        data[0].total_time
    )
};

export default BorrowCount;
```

In API I call new controller:

```
app.get('/api/toolsborrow/:id', toolController.borrowCount);
```

And controller returns SUM of *time* column where *ToolId* is *id* of tool row:

```
borrowCount(req, res) {
        const options = {
            attributes: [
                [Sequelize.fn('sum', Sequelize.col('time')), 'total_time'],
              ],
            raw: true,
            where: ({
                ToolId: req.params.id
            }),
            order: 
                []
            ,
        };


        return B_tool
        .findAll(options)
        .then(b_tool => {
            res.status(200).send(b_tool);
        })
        .catch(error => res.status(400).send(error));
    },
```

Finally, I just use this new element **BorrowCount** in List of tools:

```
    <List {...props} filters={<ToolFilter />}>
        <Datagrid rowClick="edit">
            <TextField source="id" />
            <TextField source="code" label="Kód" />
            <TextField source="name" />
            <TextField source="state" />
            <BorrowCount label="Total_sum"/>
            <NumberField source="free" />
            <DateField source="add_time" />
            <EditButton />
        </Datagrid>
    </List>
```

If someone has more elegant solution, please leave it here.